# Get id's of a ManyToMany mapping table

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I'm writing an API using Spring Boot and Hibernate where my persisted entity objects are also used as DTOs sent to and from the client. This is a simplified version of a typical entity I use:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "GROUP_STUDENT",
                     joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID"))
    @Column(name="STUDENT_ID")
    private Set<Long> groupIds;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="GROUP_STUDENT",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
    )
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

and this is the associated class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GROUP")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "groups")
    private Set<Student> students = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```

As you can see, there is a `@ManyToMany` association between `Student` and `Group`.

Since I send objects like these to the client, I choose to send only the id's of the associations and not the associations themselves. I've solved this using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16999997/how-to-load-only-ids-from-many-to-many-mapping-tables) and it works as expected.

The problem is this. When hibernate tries to persist a `Student` object, it inserts the `groups` as expected, but it also tries to insert the `groupIds` into the mapping table `GROUP_STUDENT`. This will of course fail because of the unique constraint of the mapping table composite id. And it isn't possible to mark the `groupIds` as `insertable = false` since it is an `@ElementCollection`. And I don't think I can use `@Formula` since I require a `Set` and not a reduced value.

This can of course be solved by always emptying either the `groups` of the `groupIds` before saving or persisting such an entity, but this is extremely risky and easy to forget.

So what I want is basically a read only `groupIds` in the `Student` class that loads the data from the `GROUP_STUDENT` mapping table. Is this possible? I'm grateful for any suggestions and glad to ellaborate on the question if it seems unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to solve this by making the id-collection `@Transient` and populating it using `@PostLoad`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENT")
public class Student {
    @PostLoad
    private void postLoad() {
        groupIds = groups.stream().map(Group::getId).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Transient
    private Set<Long> groupIds;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="GROUP_STUDENT",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="GROUP_ID"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="STUDENT_ID")
    )
    private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

    // getters and setters
}
```